# Returning pointer to array doesn't give expected output in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int* createReverseArray(int *array, int size)
{
    int i;
    int newArray[size];
    for(i=size-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        newArray[i] = array[size-i-1];
    }

    return newArray;
}

int main(void) {

    int myArray[] = {1,2,3,5,1};
    int myArray2[] = {1,2,3,4,2,1};
    int i;

    int size = sizeof(myArray)/sizeof(int);
    printf("Size: %d\n", size);
    int* newArray = createReverseArray(myArray, size);

    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d, ", newArray[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I printed the array within the createReverseArray function and got the correct output, but when I return the pointer to the array and then try to print the results, I think it's printing pointers to each array spot? I'm not quite sure.

This returns:

Size: 5

12341002, 1, -10772231820, -1077231812, 1074400845,

Comment: This is a classic error that I'm pretty sure has been asked about before on StackOverflow. You are returning a pointer to memory allocated inside a function, and that function will go away. The Go language is smart enough to make this work and move that memory to the heap, but C cannot do this. You have to malloc space for this array yourself.

Comment: @RayToal: It has been asked just 1000+ times ... And yes, it is a very basic error which results from not starting with the fundamental concepts of the language. Like one gets from a good C book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`newarray` is an automatic local variable. It will no longer exists once function return. Returning pointer to an automatic local variable invoke [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and in this case nothing good can be expected.

You can allocate memory diynamically and then return pointer to it

```
int *newArray = malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
```

Comment: Can I free the memory in the main function even if I called malloc in the createReverseArray() ?

Comment: @DJSweetness; Yes. Read how `free` function works.